# How do I save a randomized result (which will be different with every reload) on my webpage with local storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, local-storage, shuffle

I have made a website where you can generate a random workout, that is, a workout with 5 random exercises combined with 5 random types of reps. To generate a random amount of reps I used Math.floor(Math.random() to the array I made. To generate 5 different, random workouts I used the shuffle function in Javascript to shuffle my array every time the page reloads.

**Now I want the user to be able to save whatever result they got up on their webpage to the local storage on their computer so they can access that specific randomized workout whenever they want.** How do I go about this???

Down here I publish the code I created to generate the result.

````
// This makes the reps generate randomly in a list of 5

let maxNr = 10;

function generateRep(){ 
  let randomReps = [`4x10`,`4x8`, `4x20`, `4x12`, `4x15`,`3x10`, `3x15`, `4x5`, `5x10`, `10x10`];
  for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
  let randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNr); 
  if (randomNr==9) maxNr=9;
  let repsText = "<li>"+randomReps[randomNr]+"</li>";
  document.getElementById("repsList").innerHTML+=repsText;
  console.log(maxNr);
 }
}

//THIS IS A SHUFFLE FUNCTION 

function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }
  return array;
}

//This is the workout generator for, in this case, a chest and back workout using the shuffle function from above.

function generateWorkout() {
  let workoutList = [`Chins`, `Wide barbell row (bent over)`, `Row with machine`, `Cable pulldown`,
  `Lat pulldown`, `Bent-over dumbbell alternating row`,`Reverse fly with barbell`,`Push-ups`, 
  `Face-pull with cable`, `Seated face pull`, `Single arm lat pulldown`, `Low position row with cable`, 
  `Split stance high anchor row with cable`, `Bench Press`, `Overhead press with dumbbells or barbell`,
  ` One arm row with dumbbell`,` Inverted row`, `Close grip dumbbell press`, ];
  let shuffleWorkoutList= shuffle(workoutList);
  for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
    let workoutText = "<li>"+workoutList[i]+"</li>";
    document.getElementById("listOfWorkouts").innerHTML+=workoutText;
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Read about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on MDN. It is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of using the LocalStorage is

- save a value: `localStorage.setItem("name-or-key", "value")` where the key and value should be strings.
- get a value: `localStorage.getItem("name-or-key")`

This is how you could implement this in your snippet:

```
function generateWorkout() {
  let workoutList = [`Chins`, `Wide barbell row (bent over)`, `Row with machine`, `Cable pulldown`,
  `Lat pulldown`, `Bent-over dumbbell alternating row`,`Reverse fly with barbell`,`Push-ups`, 
  `Face-pull with cable`, `Seated face pull`, `Single arm lat pulldown`, `Low position row with cable`, 
  `Split stance high anchor row with cable`, `Bench Press`, `Overhead press with dumbbells or barbell`,
  ` One arm row with dumbbell`,` Inverted row`, `Close grip dumbbell press`, ];
  let shuffleWorkoutList= shuffle(workoutList);
  for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
    let workoutText = "<li>"+workoutList[i]+"</li>";
  };
  localStorage.setItem("workout-list", workoutList.join(","));
};
```

and

```
function load_prev_workout() {
    const prev_workout = localStorage.getItem("workout-list").split(",");
    console.log(prev_workout);
    for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
        let workoutText = "<li>"+prev_workout[i]+"</li>";
        console.log("Now use this:",workoutText,"for something.");
    };
};
```

Then call these conditionally:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("workout-list")) {
    load_prev_workout();
} else {
    generateWorkout();
};
```

**If you want to save more than one workout at a time, let the user choose a name for that workout, or give it a unique id, then use that as part of the localStorage item's name/key**